# odoo - add tablerow in sales order total costs

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to add an extra row in the sales order between the *total untaxed cost* and the *total taxes cost*. When looking at the the `report_saleorder.xml` my line should be added inside the following code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total Without Taxes</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Taxes</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="o.amount_tax"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="o.amount_total"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Since editing the core xml is not an option I was wondering if it would be possible to do this using `<xpath>` but I am unsure how to go about doing this. I already have created a `field` in my sale.py file and looking at their code my xml should be something like

```
<tr>
     <td>Insurance</td>
     <td class="text-right">
         <span t-field="o.amount_insurance" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Any help on how I would be able to do this would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are absolutely right modifying the existing code is not good idea, as when you update the module you will loose the changes so right way is not inherit the view and in this case you need to inherit the view template `report_saleorder_document` and add the required field as desired field using xpath tag :

If you are doing in the interface itself the create a new view record with following syntax and inherit it from `report_saleorder_document`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-4 pull-right']/table/tr[2]" position="after">
    <tr>
         <td>Insurance</td>
             <td class="text-right">
             <span t-field="o.amount_insurance" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
         </td>
    </tr>
    </xpath>
</data>
```

And if you are doing by code then add inherited view definition. it will should look like this :

[image]

For the changes through code create new file and add following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
  <template id="report_saleorder_insurance_inherit" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-4 pull-right']/table/tr[2]" position="after">
        <tr>
             <td>Insurance</td>
                 <td class="text-right">
                 <span t-field="o.amount_insurance" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
             </td>
        </tr>
        </xpath>
 </template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

and don’t forget to register our file under manifest

Bests

Comment: The image u show is exactly what I need!
But I don't really understand where i should place your code. Just make a new xml file for it or put it in an existing one? I tried both but it gives me `AssertionError: Did not expect element xpath there`

Comment: @ThomasS : Updated the answer with more details for code file you want todo. after adding new file update the module list and module. or use -u -d option from terminal.

Comment: I put the code you gave me in a serparate xml file and added this file to  `__openerp__.py` but i can't see any new changes. I restarted the service and the module updated without problem. Is there something i missed or any idea why it seems as if the xml is not used? Lots of thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Not Sure what you doing their but that solid code, here more specific xpath if you using sale order layout module     <xpath expr="//div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-4 pull-right']/table/tr[2]" position="after">